# How do I get my CustomListAdapter to update on notifyDatasetChange?

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

This is the first time I am building a Listview with a custom layout, so in case I have missed something obvious please just point it out.

The problem I am having that I cannot get the listview to update itself with new information after the Oncreate(); has been used. So the list is very static.

I am trying to create a custom listview adapter that looks as such:

```
public class MainListCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

static ArrayList<ListItems> DataSomething;
static Context Cont;

public MainListCustomBaseAdapter (ArrayList<ListItems> data, Context c){
    DataSomething = data;
    Cont = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return DataSomething.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return DataSomething.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     View v = convertView;
     if (v == null)
     {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)Cont.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.mainlistlayout, null);
     }

       ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ListImage);
       TextView titleView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title);
       TextView DetailItemView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.DetailItem);


       ListItems msg = DataSomething.get(position);
       image.setImageResource(msg.icon);
       titleView.setText(msg.title);
       DetailItemView.setText("ItemDetails: "+msg.ItemDetails);


    return v;
}

public void updateResults(ArrayList<MainListCustomBaseAdapter> results){
    notifyDataSetChanged();


}


}
```

My Oncreate looks like this:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


   RecipeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

    ShoppingItems = new ArrayList<ListItems>();
    RecipeList.setAdapter(new MainListCustomBaseAdapter(ShoppingItems, this));

    ListItems Detail;
    Detail = new ListItems();
    Detail.setIcon(R.drawable.food);
    Detail.setName("Food Stuff");
    Detail.setItemDetails("ItemDetailsComp");
    ShoppingItems.add(Detail);

}
```

and listitem looks like this:

```
public class ListItems {
        public int icon ;
        public String title;
        public String ItemDetails;


        public String getName() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setName(String from) {
            this.title = from;
        }

        public String getItemDetails() {
            return ItemDetails;
        }

        public void setItemDetails(String ItemDetailsComp) {
            this.ItemDetails = ItemDetailsComp;
        }

        public int getIcon() {
            return icon;
        }

        public void setIcon(int icon) {
            this.icon = icon;
        }

}
```

How do I get the listview to update dynamically? with maybe a SetInvalidatedViews() or notifyDatasetchanged()?

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Set the adapter after you have populate the `ShoppingItems`. And usually yes, `notifyDataSetChanged()` is the one to be used to *refresh* the ListView.

Comment: `MainListCustomBaseAdapter adapter = new MainListCustomBaseAdapter(ShoppingItems, this)` and then to refresh listview `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Oh my GOOOOD! Thank you guys so much! BAH! I WAS SO STRESSED OUT about this! Thank you a billion! It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below

```
   MainListCustomBaseAdapter adapter = new MainListCustomBaseAdapter(ShoppingItems, this)
   RecipeList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To refresh or update listview

```
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

`public void notifyDataSetChanged ()`

Added in API level 1

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been
>   changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Answer (score 1):

put this line after adding the element in the arraylist

RecipeList.setAdapter(new MainListCustomBaseAdapter(ShoppingItems, this));